# How to combine bar chart and bubble chart in Google chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, linechart, bubble-chart

I am trying to make a Column chart which is a combination of bar chart and bubble chart. I already have one column chart with bar chart and line chart, I want to change the line as a bubble. My current chart screenshot is below. Please check. I want to remove the line from it.

[image: the]

I have tried the series type option from bar to bubble but it is not working. I think Column chart does not support Bubble chart. Is there any other way to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray, I got the answer. lineWidth can be set to zero and we can increase the pointSize as shown below.

```
series:{1: {type: "line",pointSize: 10, lineWidth :0}
```